# Getting "Server refused to allocate pty" error when trying to connect to Bitbucket via SSH on Windows

Tags: windows, mercurial, ssh, bitbucket

I'm trying to hook up Mercurial to Bitbucket on a PC and it's being really tough. I followed the instructions here:

http://www.codza.com/mercurial-with-ssh-setup-on-windows

and I'm running pageant set to my private key. I typed this at the command line:

`plink -v hg@bitbucket.org` and I get the following output:

```
C:\mypath>plink -v hg@bitbucket.org
"skipped for briefness"
Access granted
Opened channel for session
Server refused to allocate pty
Started a shell/command
conq: invalid command syntax
Server sent command exit status 0
Disconnected: All channels closed
```

My friend got the same error when he tried it on his PC. Can you help explain what the problem is or how to debug?

Running `plink ssh://hg@bitbucket.org` gives `Using username ssh://hg` and `Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available.`

Thanks for your help,
Kevin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot connect to Bitbucket like that and get a login shell -- their backend process (called `conq`) will only accept Mercurial commands. With TortoiseHg, you don't have to do anything special -- so `hg push ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/...` should just work out of the box.

Using HTTPS is generally a nicer option for Bitbucket and as we discussed on IRC, there are [plenty of ways to cache the passwords](http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/remote/#caching-of-http-s-credentials).